# how to calculate the time complexity for the following code?

Tags: java

```
For (int i=1; i <=n;i/=2){
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

For the time complexity about the above coding, is ot log (n)?

Thanks!

Comment: `i /= 2`? You have an infinite loop unless `n` is negative.

Comment: Hi, kiheru. So you mean the question have problem? But this is last year paper. I don't understand how to analyze to calculate the time complexity.

Comment: It may or may not have problem. @sasha.sochka gave you a more complete answer (I missed `n == 0` case). After first iteration (if done at all) `i == 0` because integer division `1 / 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

- If `n > 0`: It's time complexity is `O(∞)` because the loop will never end
- If `n <= 0`: It's time complexity is `O(1)`
  because the loop will not be executed